# Estimating adjusted rate ratios for categorical independent variable measured only as population percents

Tags: epidemiology, multilevel-analysis

I have counts of people with a condition, by age (5-year groups), sex, and area (100-200 areas).

For each area, I have:

- estimated population by age (5-year groups) and sex,
- estimated population percent living in city, small town or rural (sum
  to 100%),
- estimated population in high, middle and low socioeconomic status
  (sum to 100%), and
- estimated population proportion treated (via food or water supply
  fortification).

I know nothing about individual-level correlation between rurality and socioeconomic status (or even if it's the same across areas). I expect proportion treated is near 100% in cities, lower in small towns, much lower in rural areas.

Researcher wants adjusted rate (or odds) ratios for having the condition (and p-values) for rural vs cities, low vs high SES, untreated vs treated, young vs older.

Can I produce valid estimates?

If so, how should I model it?

Answer (score 1):

Multilevel analysis based on aggregate data leads to ecological fallacy.  Here is an interesting paper to read:  http://www.stanford.edu/class/ed260/freedman549.pdf

Comment: Could you perhaps summarize the main points of that paper so that this reply remains self-contained.

Comment: @Omar So are you saying no I cannot produce valid estimates? Or are you saying I cannot produce valid estimates from multilevel analysis? Is there any way i can produce valid estimates?